# MySQL - Full Text Search - reverse

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I know how to get all results which contain a few words:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`row`) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But how I can all results which **not contain words**: "word1", "word2" ?? I need operator, something like "NOT IN". So how I can get from database everything records which not contain specific words in query using full text search?

Thanks.

Comment: `NOT IN` is a valid construct.

Comment: I know and this is why I asked about it here... I want something alternative to get all results which not contain specific words.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question then to not read, "I need [...] Something like not in" but to tell us more specificity what you're looking for.

Comment: I specified everything in my question. The question is short - how I can get from database everything records which not contain specific words in query using full text search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `NOT` to negate the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOT MATCH (`row`) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The `MATCH` condition is **true** on rows where it finds the words, and **false** where it does not find the words. Use `NOT` reverses the true/false result on each row.

Just like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOT row = 'abc123'
```

would be true on all rows that are *not* the specific value 'abc123'.

Comment: "NOT MATCH" - this is it. Thanks !